# A browser and maybe an extension to translate websites

Tags: web-browser, translation

I live in Turkey but I speak only Russian and English. I want to browse Turkish websites and shop in Turkish online shops. What's the best browser (and, possibly, an extension for it) for Linux, Android, or iPad to translate websites?

Desiderata, sorted by priority descending:

1. High quality translation.
2. When the translation is turned on, if I click on a link that leads to a website in the same language, it should also get translated.
3. It should let me log into websites and see translated versions of whatever I would see while logged in.
4. Good UI.
5. It shouldn't break websites.
6. It shouldn't send my cookies or passwords I use to 3rd party servers.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome has an in-built translator. You just right-click on a page and choose Translate to English. You can change the preferred language from the three dots at the top right after you click that option.

[image: Language Option]

If you are not using Chrome, there  is an [extension of Google Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-translate/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb?hl=tr) that does the same thing, it's also possible to translate only the words you choose. Despite being in Chrome Web Store, many browsers support extensions from there.

You can set an option in Chrome to automatically offer translating.

[image: Chrome Language Option]

Sorry, i haven't found any free extension that automatically translates pages upon loading, so i am gonna have to give [Meta Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mate-translate-%E2%80%93-translat/ihmgiclibbndffejedjimfjmfoabpcke) as an example.